# Prettier collapses empty loops in VSCode, how do I change this?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I have two very strong habits that work together to make the way Prettier formats JS code a problem for me. I set out a template for my code before I start to type the logic itself, and I save after every little break I may have. Let's say I'm creating a new class. I'd type out the code like this:

```
class Object {
  constructor() {

  }

  function1() {

  }
}
```

I would then save this code before I start giving it variables or logic in the methods. However, when I save, it will auto format the code. I like this in almost every case, since I like my code to look pretty. Except if I did this for the above code, it would turn out looking like this:

```
class Object {
  constructor() {}

  function1() {}
}
```

I'd really like to change this, because it's such a small problem but it drives me mad to have to go back and add a new line between the curly braces every time, even though I know I have to do it before I save, I just do it out of pure muscle memory.

Does anybody have any help they could offer?

Comment: why not just separate formatting from saving?

Comment: Because in every other scenario it makes it much easier to have better looking code and keep it readable as I go, especially with larger projects. I'd rather just disable the option to collapse empty curly braces on format.

Comment: https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#empty-lines https://stackoverflow.com/q/60915308/11107541

Comment: I've read those already and neither of them touch on my problem specifically

Comment: then you should have said so to save everyone's time. please edit your question post to say so.

Comment: The second link specifically mentions _Prettier is considered an "opinionated" formatter, which means it doesn't let you choose things like that. If you want more control over the formatting, you can use a different formatter._ 

I think that should be the answer to your question. If you want to work with an opionated formatter like prettier, *you* have to adjust because the tool will not.  If you don't want to adjust your flow, pick another formatting tool.

Comment: When you type out the constructer() {}, put a few letters between the brackets. That will open the brackets the way you want when you save